# Java: Keep order using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I have multiple threads that log some info throug my svc object.

```
public class SomeObject implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        svc.log("Reading file ...");
        .. some stuff...
        svc.log("Processing numbers ...");
        ... more stuff ...
        svc.log("Calculating power ...");
        ... and more stuff ...
    }
}
```

The log processing was too expensive, so I decided to use another thread to do the log process.
First I created a new thread per each log operation. It was faster but I ran out memory. So I decided to create a Singleton thread that just log the messages. It's faster and use less memory, but now I have a new problem: the log is being written in other order...
Sometimes I have

```
Calculating power...
Reading file...
Processing numbers ...
```

instead of

```
Reading file...
Processing numbers ...
Calculating power...
```

I tried using `BlockingQueue`, so instead log directly, I put the messages in the queue and then just read and log the messages in it, but I have the same problem with the order.

I have another idea: put the messages into a synchronized collection, specifying an order throug a variable and pop the elements depending on the variable, but it sounds weird.

Any ideas to keep using of threads and keep order insertion?

Comment: Why not just use a logging library like log4J?

Comment: It's not a simple logging, I have to do more things in my log process

Comment: You should post the code of the `svc` class

Comment: How can you be using a blocking queue and get messages in disorder? If you are using a FIFO approach, how can your messages be in disorder in the queue? Could it be that you are putting the messages in disorder in the queue itself?

Comment: Exactly! the problem is not the retrieving process, is the insertion. Maybe because the insertion is inside a thread. If i execute my object SomeObject  with ´run´ method instead ´start´ method, I have the correct order

Comment: At the end of the day if you're running multi-threaded code, there is no "before" and "after" any more, unless you force threads to wait for each other. So it doesn't matter what data structure you're using to record the log calls, you'll get the messages in an arbitrary order. Unless you make the calls themselves ordered.

Comment: @OscarSan Yes, because then your code runs in a single thread.

Comment: It would be good if you explained what other things you have to do in the log process because most logging frameworks (like `log4j`) are extensible, so it's quite possible that writing a custom appender is the easiest way forward.

Comment: Im logging into the event viewer throug Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Comment: I'm logging into the event viewer throug      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) and executing ohter commands in the same way

Comment: Then instead of a BlockingQueue use PriorityQueue and make sure messages are sorted/compared by timestamp. Every message gets a timestamp when it is created, and before it is put into the PriorityQueue. Then, regardless of where they come from, they will be consumed in the "right order".

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I've read about `PriorityBlockingQueue` (because I need "the blocking" behaviour ) and maybe this could be a solution. I'll try it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You can put the messages in a [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), which is thread-safe and will keep the elements ordered according to their natural order or else according to a comparator (e.g. their timestamp).  There's also a [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) that orders according to they keys' natural ordering.

Comment: Timestamps won't enforce the "correct" order either, first of all they have a limited resolution, secondly, the problem seems to be that the "natural" order is not what OP wants.